# Почему не инициализируются бины?

Tags: java, spring

Есть несколько классов объекты которых должны создаваться спрингом:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(name = "command")
    @Scope("singleton")
    CommandManagerImpl commandManager() {
        return new CommandManagerImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "analyzer")
    @Scope("singleton")
    TasksAnalyzerImpl tasksAnalyzer() {
        return new TasksAnalyzerImpl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "robot")
    @Scope("singleton")
    HumanizeRobot humanizeRobot() {
        return new HumanizeRobot();
    }
}
```

И сами классы

```
@Component
public class CommandManagerImpl implements CommandManager {

    private Map<String, Command> commands;

    @Autowired
    private HumanizeRobot robot;

    @Autowired
    private TasksAnalyzer tasksAnalyzer;

    private void initCommands() {
        commands.put("task.list", new CommandImpl("task.list", robot, "update.task.list"));

    }
    //...
}

@Component
public class TasksAnalyzerImpl implements TasksAnalyzer {... тут внутри спринга нет}

@Component
public class HumanizeRobot {... тут внутри спринга нет}
```

Вызываю вот так:

```
ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);
CommandManagerImpl commandManager = context.getBean(CommandManagerImpl.class);
```

Но падает с ошибкой в месте где есть попытка использовать объект `HumanizeRobot` который должен был создать спринг:

```
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2d38eb89: startup date [Mon Dec 04 06:31:05 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Не понимаю почему бины не создаются. Подскажите пожалуйста почему поля помеченные `@Autowired` не создаются спрингом? Спасибо.

Comment: у вас все классы в одном пакете? и выложите весь стек ошибки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @ComponentScan

Не указаны пакеты для сканирования.